# How to get the button click event of a bootstrap modal popup in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i am using MVC 5 in my project, i have link of which when a user clicks, pops up a bootstrap modal window for user to enter new record, the view has a datatable which displays existing records, i have been able to handle this part, now i want to be able to insert user's input from the modal pop up and show the record on the datatable without user refreshing the page?

here is my code:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
<!-- start: BOOTSTRAP EXTENDED MODALS -->

<div id="responsive" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760" style="display: none;top:50px;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            &times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Responsive</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Othernames, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Othernames, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Othernames, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light-grey">
                Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">
                Save changes
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ends: BOOTSTRAP EXTENDED MODALS -->
</form>
```

i will appreciate your assistance.

Comment: If you want to update data in the page without refreshing then you are going to have to use an ajax call in javascript to submit/fetch the data, and then update the page.

Comment: any link to as how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I edit code for you copy this code
This is your head

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
  <title>Bootstrap-modal by jschr</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.6/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.6/css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

and this is your body

```
    <body>
<button class="demo btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack1">View Demo</button>
<div id="stack1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Stack One</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="1" />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-tabindex="2" />
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack2">Launch modal</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.6/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-modal/2.2.6/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

refer below sample code :

```
     <form role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="formName" method="POST">
    <!-- start: BOOTSTRAP EXTENDED MODALS -->

    <div id="responsive" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760" style="display: none;top:50px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Responsive</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Othernames, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Othernames, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Othernames, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light-grey">
                    Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" onclick="saveChanges()" class="btn btn-blue">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ends: BOOTSTRAP EXTENDED MODALS -->
    </form>
    <script>
    function saveChanges()
    {
    var formData = $('#formName').serialize();
    $.ajax(
        url: @Url.Action("post url")
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
// write here code to add new record in datatable
        //var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    //table.row.add( {
      //      "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        //    "position":   "System Architect",
          //  "salary":     "$3,120",
           // "start_date": "2011/04/25",
           // "office":     "Edinburgh",
           // "extn":       "5421"
        //} ).draw();
        })
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: how do link this to modal popup save event, that is, i want to see the new record on the datatable as soon as i click on the save button, also, how do i assign textbox values to the above Javascript?

Comment: you simply add onclick event on popup save button like  <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" onclick="saveChanges()">
                Save changes
            </button>,  so you can write ajax code to save data and after saving data Add row in datatable

Comment: refer above modified answer.